# R update removes all R packages

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, r

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2 (5.8.0-53-generic) and have R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31) -- "Shake and Throw" installed.
Today I updated the system with `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` and suddenly all my R packages were gone (only left with the base packages).
Luckily I had a Timeshift snapshot from yesterday so that I could go back pre-update.
When I now run `sudo apt update` and `apt list --upgradable` I get this list:

```
gstreamer1.0-alsa/focal-updates,focal-security 1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-4]
gstreamer1.0-gl/focal-updates,focal-security 1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-4]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps/focal-updates,focal-security 1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-4]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/focal-updates,focal-security 1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-4]
gstreamer1.0-x/focal-updates,focal-security 1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-4]
initramfs-tools-bin/focal-updates 0.136ubuntu6.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.136ubuntu6.4]
initramfs-tools-core/focal-updates,focal-updates 0.136ubuntu6.5 all [upgradable from: 0.136ubuntu6.4]
initramfs-tools/focal-updates,focal-updates 0.136ubuntu6.5 all [upgradable from: 0.136ubuntu6.4]
libgstreamer-gl1.0-0/focal-updates,focal-security 1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-4]
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0/focal-updates,focal-security 1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.2-4]
liblzf1/focal-updates,focal-security 3.6-2~ubuntu1.20.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.6-2~ubuntu1.20.04.1]
libssl-dev/focal-updates 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.3]
libssl1.1/focal-updates 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.3]
openssl/focal-updates 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.3]
r-base-core/focal-cran40 4.1.0-1.2004.0 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.0.5-1.2004.0]
r-base-dev/focal-cran40 4.1.0-1.2004.0 all [upgradable from: 4.0.5-1.2004.0]
r-base-html/focal-cran40 4.1.0-1.2004.0 all [upgradable from: 4.0.5-1.2004.0]
r-base/focal-cran40 4.1.0-1.2004.0 all [upgradable from: 4.0.5-1.2004.0]
r-doc-html/focal-cran40 4.1.0-1.2004.0 all [upgradable from: 4.0.5-1.2004.0]
r-recommended/focal-cran40 4.1.0-1.2004.0 all [upgradable from: 4.0.5-1.2004.0]
virtualbox-dkms/focal-updates,focal-security 6.1.16-dfsg-6~ubuntu1.20.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 6.1.16-dfsg-6~ubuntu1.20.04.1]
virtualbox-qt/focal-updates,focal-security 6.1.16-dfsg-6~ubuntu1.20.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 6.1.16-dfsg-6~ubuntu1.20.04.1]
virtualbox/focal-updates,focal-security 6.1.16-dfsg-6~ubuntu1.20.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 6.1.16-dfsg-6~ubuntu1.20.04.1]
```

Has anyone had this problem as well and how can I update everything without losing the R packages again?

Comment: It's hard to give a definitive answer, but removal of a lot of packages sometimes occur when there is a conflict.  And I encounter that when I update the Ubuntu version...which doesn't seem to be the case here with you.  But, I don't see why you chose to use Timeshift, though.  Why can't you let the system uninstall "everything" and then manually install them back?  Then, you'd get the latest version of R and its packages...which is presumably your point?

Comment: Yes I could do that, but I have a lot of packages installed and it will take ages to put all of them back. I have updated R before without any issues like this.

Comment: Again, it's hard to tell you without more information.  It might be there might be a package "ABC" that is available for the previous version of R (which you are using), but does not exist for the new version.  Thus, it automatically gets removed since the R it depends on will no longer exist.  That's possible...it's a bit hard to say without more information.  But, presumably, you wouldn't have to do this every time you update (let's hope!).  So, it might take "ages", but it'll be a one-off...

Comment: By the way, Ubuntu 20.04's R should be 3.6.3-2, according to [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/r-base-core).  Are you pulling in R from other sources?  If so, you should mention this in your question.  If you deviate from the standard repository, then many things can happen...

Comment: Nothing in the output suggests *removal*. Everything in the output suggests *upgrade*. The information so far seems contradictory, so the question is currently unanswerable.